# PHPWord exception: Could not close zip file

Tags: php-7, phpword

I'm trying to create a word .doc file from word template with PHPWord library in php7 (xampp windows7), but it retrieves an exception `Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception: Could not close zip file D:\AppData\Local\Temp\Php470E.tmp`

I've read in other discussions that it's because folder permissions, but I'm permitting read and write permissions in the folder in which I want to save the file..
Someone have any suggestion to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change template file extension from .doc to .docx (just open your template in Microsoft Word and save as template.docx). In my case, it solved this problem. My phpWord version is -> "0.14.0".

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up the permissions on your Temp directory. On a linux system I had the same issue, and resolved it with a chmod 775. The "user" doing the writing is not the owner of the directory.